# Vector reinterpret cast ARM Neon

Tags: c++, arm, neon, reinterpret-cast

I have a uint32x4_t ARM NEON vector register. I want to "shuffle" this 4 uint32_t with 
[vtbx2](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491h/BABFEIAI.html) and [vext](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491h/BABBHDHE.html)

The interface for the table lookup intrinsics expecting `uint8x8_t`. This seems to be possible with a [cast](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491h/BABGIABH.html) especially because the documentation states that the

> "[...] conversions do not change the bit pattern represented by the vector."

I tried it with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <arm_neon.h>
#include <bitset>

int main() {
   uint32_t* data = new uint32_t[4];
   uint32_t* result = new uint32_t[4];
   //00 00 0A 0A
   data[0] = 2570;
   //00 0A 00 0A
   data[1] = 655370;
   //0A 0A 0A 0A
   data[2] = 168430090;
   //00 00 00 0A
   data[3] = 10;

   //load data
   uint32x4_t dataVec = vld1q_u32(data);
   //cast to uint8
   uint8x16_t dataVecByteTmp = vreinterpretq_u8_u32(dataVec);

   uint32_t* tmpData = new uint32_t[4];
   //store original data
   vst1q_u32(tmpData, dataVec);

   std::cout << "Orig Data:" << std::endl;
   for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
      std::bitset<32> f(tmpData[i]);
      std::cout << f << std::endl;
   }

   uint8_t* high = new uint8_t[16];
   //store uint8 data
   vst1q_u8(high, dataVecByteTmp);

   std::cout << "unsigned output" << std::endl;
   for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
      std::cout << (unsigned)high[i] << std::endl;
   }
   std::cout << "bitwise output" << std::endl;
   for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
      std::bitset<8> b(high[i]);
      std::cout << b << std::endl;
   }
   delete[] tmpData;
   delete[] high;    
   delete[] data;
   delete[] result;
   return 0;
}
```

One can compile it with:

> g++ -march=native -mfpu=neon -std=c++14 main.cpp

The ouput looks like the following:

```
Orig Data:
00000000000000000000101000001010
00000000000010100000000000001010
00001010000010100000101000001010
00000000000000000000000000001010

unsigned output
10 
10 
0 
0 
10 
0 
10 
0 
10 
10 
10 
10 
10 
0 
0 
0 

bitwise output
00001010
00001010
00000000
00000000
00001010
00000000
00001010
00000000
00001010
00001010
00001010
00001010
00001010
00000000
00000000
00000000
```

For a better overview, I changed the formatting a bit:

```
Orig (uint32_t):
00000000 00000000 00001010 00001010
00000000 00001010 00000000 00001010
00001010 00001010 00001010 00001010
00000000 00000000 00000000 00001010

New (uint8_t):
10 10 0   0 
10  0 10  0 
10 10 10 10 
10  0  0  0

New (uint8_t bitwise):
00001010 00001010 00000000 00000000
00001010 00000000 00001010 00000000
00001010 00001010 00001010 00001010
00001010 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

As one can see, the result is not like expected. Does anyone knows whether I did something wrong or is this just a bug?

Sincerely

Comment: I'd actually recommend using boost.simd, it scales well on any architecture.

Comment: You might want to read about endianness.

Comment: Why is endianness important here. I thought the bit pattern is not changed at all?!

Comment: @Hymir The *pattern* in the vector register is not changed, the *interpretation* of that bit-pattern by the constructor of `std::bitset` is changed.

Comment: So that means, that internally everything is fine but std::bitset is the reason for that strange output? To be honest, I doubt it. Because if I print the array like that: std::cout << (unsigned)high[i] << " ";
I get the following result:
10 10 0 0 10 0 10 0 10 10 10 10 10 0 0 0
Which is ALSO wrong (note the 4th element for instance)